# okhttp 3.7.0 SSL Shutdown failed threw UnknownHostException and not SSLException

Tags: ssl, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

While making a network request with low connectivity very rarely I see that I get

`<-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host ....`

while my server seems to have got the request correctly. I found 1 instance of it with device logs which shows actually an SSLException happened

`D/NativeCrypto: jniThrowException: javax/net/ssl/SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x7dc365f080: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
D/NativeCrypto: jniThrowException: javax/net/ssl/SSLException: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x7dc365f080: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe`

My question is why does okhttp and retrofit throw UnknownHostException and not SSLException, and is there a way to actually get the SSLException as currently my app thinks the request did not go while server processes that request.

I am using

`okhttp:3.10.0
retrofit:2.2.0
adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0`